# can 'I have it uploaded' and I've uploaded it' be interchangeable?

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice, causative-have

Can **I have it uploaded** and **I've uploaded it** be interchangeable?

Is there any differences between them?

More question relating to **I have it uploaded**:

- Is **uploaded** used as adjective?

When I'm writing on my own, this is so confusing.

Somebody can give me more examples to understand like **I have it uploaded**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *some* contexts where ***I have it uploaded*** and ***I've uploaded it*** carry the same (relevant) information, so you could say they're "interchangeable" in those specific contexts. For example, suppose you're in a wi-fi cafe with a friend...

> *Do you want to listen to my new song? ...*
>    1: *I've uploaded it.*
>    2: *I have it uploaded.*

(note that *both* alternatives above could reasonably be followed by something like *...into my public Dropbox folder, to which I emailed you a link this morning*).

But in most contexts there would be at least a *shade* of difference in meaning (if the upload process was difficult/unusual, for example, the speaker might attempt to emphasise this by using the more "verby" construction #1). As OP suspects, ***uploaded*** in #2 is effectively an "adjectival" usage. Compare...

> *Do you want a beer? ...*
>    3: *I have some **stored** in the fridge.* (past participle used adjectivally)
>    4: *I have some **cold** in the fridge*. (explicitly adjectival usage)

(where it's contextually unlikely the speaker means *someone else* stocks his fridge with cold beer!).

---

The construction *TO HAVE [something] [X'ed - past participle]* can also be used to mean *to get someone else to X something for you* (where context may imply either a "one-off" or habitual process; the syntax itself implies nothing on that front). But this is a declining usage - people increasingly say [*(He) **gets** his car serviced (by a local garage)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22gets+his+car+serviced%22) rather than [***...has*** his car serviced.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22has+his+car+serviced%22)

Comment: This is the best explanation ever! I've been confused about that usage in grammar. it's really helpful! Thank you very much for the excellent explanation.